# program finished after send an email

Tags: python, email, client, twisted

The Email class is tested and has got capabilities to send an email when valid credentials are in use. The problem become when I'm doing use multiple protocols from twisted; in example when the protocols twisted mail and twisted DNS or twisted IRC.

The created code will run endless and when an event is triggered then I wish to receive an email reporting the issue, such as DNS could not resolve a valid domain, DNS service is down, etc. but when an email is received then the program exit (return code 0), therefore the class Email should contains some piece of code which I misleaded, I already check the API but there is not clue about what I missing from.

The class that I'm using currently to send an email:

```
class Email:
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.smtp_server = "SMTP"
    self.user_name = "MAIL@DOMAIN"
    self.user_password = "MAIL_PASSWORD"
    self.portTLS = 587
    self.portSSL = 465

def sendEmail(self, m):
    contextFactory = ClientContextFactory()
    contextFactory.method = SSLv3_METHOD

    resultDeferred = Deferred()
    senderFactory = ESMTPSenderFactory(
    self.user_name,
    self.user_password,
    self.user_name,
    m.to,
    m.text,
    resultDeferred,
    contextFactory=contextFactory)

    reactor.connectTCP(self.smtp_server, self.portTLS, senderFactory)
    resultDeferred.addCallbacks(self.cbSentMessage, self.ebSentMessage)
    return resultDeferred

def cbSentMessage(self, result):
    print "Message sent"
    reactor.stop()

def ebSentMessage(self, err):
    err.printTraceback()
    reactor.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `reactor.stop` to stop your program after `resultDeferred` fires.  If you stop doing that, your program will no longer exit.

(Also, you should get rid of the call to `threading.Thread.__init__`, that is unnecessary and almost certainly causing other bugs.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes user Glyph was right, now I get feeling like a fool to did do the question now :'''(

The solution was remove the reactor.stop() on the callback functions, therefore these function are now as:

```
 def cbSentMessage(self, result):
    print "Message sent"
```

in the another one is not necesary since the function is called when an error is trigerred, however I change it anyway:

```
 def ebSentMessage(self, err):
    err.printTraceback()
```